# Multithreading: Using BeginInvoke inside lock statement ok?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it a good programming practice to use asynchronous operations inside a lock construct. For eg,

```
lock(objLocker)
{

    myDispatchder.BeginInvoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
        new Action(() =>
                    {
                      // ..code..

                    }
}
```

Comment: it's okay, but doesn't bring anything in the form like you are using it.

Comment: You need to let us know what you are trying to control access to in your code. The current code doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 7):

If that is the *only* thing that you are protecting, then it would be redundant; there is no need to `lock` for `BeginInvoke`. Actually, it would be very *harmful* if that was `Invoke`, and the method called (the `// ..code..`) *also* tried to take a lock on `objLocker` - you would deadlock yourself. At the moment, it does nothing useful, and has the *possibility* to cause harm 3 maintenance releases down the line. In the more general case, if there *was* something that needed protecting, I would separate the two tasks, i.e.

```
lock(objLocker)
{
    // do some stuff
}
myDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

This then avoids any potential issues later on.

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous operations within a `lock` does nothing except make the code more complicated for no reason and to introduce possible deadlocks.

Give your code example I can suggest that the following is probably far more useful:

```
myDispatchder.BeginInvoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
    new Action(() =>
    {
        lock(objLocker)
        {
            // ..code..
        }
    }));
```

Comment: I am trying to understand an already written code that is just using begininvoe inside lock()

Comment: @user1527958 - Then you need to let us know that in the question and provide us with a more complete section of code.